# Getting Waste space on the bottom of jFrame

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have created a Jframe with scrollbar. When I run the code getting lots of waste space in th bottom and unable to remove that space.Please help me.i am using GroupLayout in eclipse. As there is lots of waste space , my form become to large so unable to print the form as half of the form is printed and when i save in jpeg its showing very small font

Comment: Show us what you have so far, your code or screen shot of your frame at least.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. To remove bottom waste space first find the last component of the jframe and go to source code of eclipse find addGap method with some number argument, below of that last component like addGap(511), here change this number to smaller number according to your need of free space in the bottom.I am writing this so that if anyone need help can get the answer.Thanks

Comment: A [screenshot](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) would make this answer easier to understand.